# React-apollo update vs refetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am using react-apollo and have been for quite some time. One thing that has already been a problem for me is the fact that [refetch doesn't work when using a mutation](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2300) This has been a know issue for as long as I have been using the app.

I have got round this by using the `refetch` prop that is available on a query.

```
    <Query query={query} fetchPolicy={fetchPolicy} {...props}>
      {({ loading, data, error, refetch }) => {
     ... pass down to mutation
    </Query>
```

However I am now reading in the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/#updating-the-cache) that you recieve 
an update method as part of a mutation and you should use this to update your application after a mutation.

Can you use the `update` function to update your UI's data and have it update after finishing a mutation? If you can, is this the standard way to do updates now?

*Using refetchQueries not working

[image]

As you can see in the image the `console.info()` displays that the `data.status = "CREATED";` but the request coming back from the mutation directly is `data.status = "PICKED";` `PICKED` is the correct and uptodate information in the DB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order of preference, your options are:

1. **Do nothing**. For regular updates to an individual node, as long as the mutation returns the mutated result, Apollo will update the cache automatically for you. When this fails to work as expected, it's usually because the query is missing the `id` (or `_id`) field. When an `id` field is not available, a custom [dataIdFromObject](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#normalization) function should be provided to the InMemoryCache constructor. Automatic cache updates also fail when people set the `addTypename` option to `false`.
2. **Use `update`.** The `update` function will run after your mutation completes, and lets you manipulate the cache directly. This is necessary if the mutation affects a field returning a list of nodes. Unlike simple updates, Apollo has no way to infer whether the list should be updated (and how) following the mutation, so we have to directly update the cache ourselves. This is typically necessary following create and delete mutations, but may also be needed after an update mutation if the updated node should be added or removed to some field that returns a list. The [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/#updating-the-cache) go into a good deal of detail explaining how to do this.

```
<Mutation
  mutation={ADD_TODO}
  update={(cache, { data: { addTodo } }) => {
    const { todos } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_TODOS });
    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_TODOS,
      data: { todos: todos.concat([addTodo]) },
    });
  }}
>
  {(addTodo) =>(...)}
</Mutation>
```

3. **Use `refetchQueries`.** Instead of updating the cache, you may also provide a `refetchQueries` function, which should return an array of objects representing the queries to refetch. This is generally less desirable than using `update` since it requires one or more additional calls to the server. However, it may be necessary if the mutation does not return enough information to correctly update the cache manually. NOTE: The returned array may also be an [array of strings](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2991#issuecomment-365759035) representing operation names, though this is not well documented.

```
<Mutation
  mutation={ADD_TODO}
  refetchQueries={() => [
    { query: TODOS_QUERY, variables: { foo: 'BAR' } },
  ]}
>
  {(addTodo) =>(...)}
</Mutation>
```

4. **Use `refetch`**. As you already showed in your question, it's possible to use the `refetch` function provided by a `Query` component inside your `Mutation` component to refetch that specific query. This is fine if your `Mutation` component is already nested inside the `Query` component, but generally using `refetchQueries` will be a cleaner solution, particularly if multiple queries need to be refetched.
5. **Use `updateQueries`**. This is a legacy option that's no longer well-documented, but provided similar functionality to `update` before `update` was added. It should not be used as it may be deprecated in the future.

**UPDATE:**

You may also set up your schema in such a way that queries can be refetched as part of your mutation. See [this article](https://medium.com/@danielrearden/a-better-refetch-flow-for-apollo-client-7ff06817b052) for more details.

Comment: Oh wow... I did not realise that it would update if you supply a query to the mutation that it will auto update. If I do a `mutation something(){}` no data is returned, so for option 1. I need to supply a query along with the mutation I assume? Also thank you for the reply :)

Comment: You'd need to provide some kind of selection set regardless, unless your mutation just returns a scalar. But to answer your question, effectively, yes. Keep in mind, again, there's limitations to this mechanism as outlined in the answer. Check the normalization section in the docs for more details.

Comment: Ye I believe this will be my major problem then, `mutation returns the mutated result` . If I am correct I can manually map all of my data structures using `InMemoryCache({ dataIdFromObject`  I have updated my question to include an image of why the `refetchQueries` does not work. Again I believe it is this mapping. Thank you a bloody ton for help too mate. Super helpful answer!!!

Comment: Ooo I think the issue could possible be because we are using `graph-lodash` I will play around with this

Comment: Wow... remove lodash.. problem solves!! You life saver Daniel. I will try to mention this in all of the github places I find people having similar problems. I've just recreated the `transform` that lodash was given us in our `apollo.js` component

Comment: `graphql-lodash` is an experimental project and probably shouldn't be used in production. I can't speak to how it would interact with Apollo's caching logic, but it sounds like there was some incongruity there. Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: If you need some more points Daniel :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205665/nest-a-query-inside-mutation-graphql