# Nest a query inside mutation graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

As you need to include a `query` inside of your mutation to get the internal cache to update after a mutation I have now come across a situation where I 
have a `query` with a `function` that accepts `variables`.  I cannot find a way to include this query inside the mutation.

I thought I may need to pass all variables inside the mutation including those that are needed for the query, but this makes no sense.

## Works correctly, this will redraw once the mutation has finished

```
export const GET_PICK_TICKETS = gql`
  {
    allPickTickets {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          createdBy
          createdAt
          status
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export const MARK_PICK_TICKET_COMPELTE = gql`
  mutation markPickTicketAsCompleted($id: Int!) {
    updatePickTicketById(input: { id: $id, pickTicketPatch: { status: "PICKED" } }) {
      clientMutationId
      query ${GET_PICK_TICKETS}
    }
  }
`
```

## Does not work

When using a query function it will fail

```
  mutation updateMemberTaskById($id: Int!, $startedAt: Datetime!) {
    updateMemberTaskById(input: { id: $id, memberTaskPatch: { startedAt: $startedAt, status: "STARTED" } }) {
      clientMutationId
      query getLocationSet($locationSetId: Int!, $internalId: Int, $jobcardIds: [String!]) {
        locationSet: locationSetById(id: $locationSetId) {
          id
          set: setBySetId {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 * please ignore that the variables are not being used in the query.
```

error produced from [graphql formatter](http://toolbox.sangria-graphql.org/format):

```
Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid input ""STARTED" } }) {\n      clientMutationId\n      query getLocationSet($", expected Argument, SelectionSet, Value, Directives or ObjectField (line 2, column 94):
    updateMemberTaskById(input: { id: $id, memberTaskPatch: { startedAt: $startedAt, status: "STARTED" } }) {                                                                                                 
                                                                                             ^
```

Maybe I do not need to do a query, but according to this [answer I do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956197/240363).

Comment: Yes, you need to declare all the variables at the top level, where you *name* your global query. Doesn't really matter where and how deeply nested you use those variables afterwards, but they must all be declared with your named query. I think that's the beauty of it, being able to build customized queries on the fly.

Comment: I will give this a whirl tomorrow :D Please go ahead and add an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I was able to pass the variables no problem :) But now I need to work out why it doesn't update the local cache.. :/