# Update Apollo cache after object creation

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

What are all the different ways of updating the Apollo [InMemoryCache](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/tree/master/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory) after a mutation? [From the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation), I can see:

1. [Id-based updates](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-a-single-existing-entity) which Apollo performs automatically

   - Happens for single updates to existing objects only.
   - Requires an `id` field which uniquely identifies each object, or the cache must be configured with a `dataIdFromObject` function which provides a unique identifier.
2. "Manual" cache updates via [update functions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates)

   - Required for object creation, deletion, or updates of multiple objects.
   - Involves calling `cache.writeQuery` with details including which query should be affected and how the cache should be changed.
3. Passing the `refetchQueries` option to the `useMutation` hook

   - The calling code says which queries should be re-fetched from the API, Apollo does the fetching, and the results replace whatever is in the cache for the given queries.

Are there other ways that I've missed, or have I misunderstood anything about the above methods?

I am confused because I've been reading the code of a project which uses Apollo for all kinds of mutations, including creations and deletions, but I don't see any calls to `cache.writeQuery`, nor any usage of `refetchQueries`. How does the cache get updated after creations and deletions without either of those?

In my own limited experience with Apollo, the cache is not automatically updated after an object creation or deletion, not even if I define `dataIdFromObject`. I have to update the cache myself by writing update functions.

So I'm wondering if there is some secret config I've missed to make Apollo handle it for me.

Comment: If we're talking about updating an item that's already in the cache, then, no, you don't need to do anything extra provided that the item has a unique `id` or `_id` field **or** you provide a custom `dataIdFromObject` implementation. There are ways you can mess up your client configuration, but it's impossible to know exactly what's wrong without seeing the code. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code where this is not happening, otherwise the answer to this question is simply "no."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956197/6024220

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. My question is really about object creations - not items already in the cache. How can the cache know about object creations without `cache.writeQuery` or `refetchQueries`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. But then, your assertions are still generally correct -- an item that's created won't be inserted into any Lists in the cache since Apollo doesn't know, based on business logic, whether it belongs to any of the existing Lists. The **only** exception I can imagine is if the object creation mutation returns the parent field of the List in question. Again, if there's some code that doesn't behave this way, it'd be good to share it.

Comment: I think the parent field thing is the answer - it lines up with what I can see in the API responses after object creations. Thank you! If you'd like to add an answer which briefly explains what is going on, I'd be glad to accept it. I was not able to make a minimal example because I had a large existing codebase showing good behaviour, not bad...it just wasn't written in the way I expected from reading the Apollo docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to create or delete a node and have Apollo automatically update the cache to reflect the change is to return the parent field of whatever field contains the updated List field. For example, let's say we have a schema like this:

```
type Query {
  me: User
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  posts: [Post!]!
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  body: String!
}
```

By convention, if we had a mutation to add a new post, the mutation field would return the created post.

```
type Mutation {
  writePost(body: String!): Post!
}
```

However, we could have it return the logged in User instead (the same thing the `me` field returns):

```
type Mutation {
  writePost(body: String!): User!
}
```

by doing so, we enable the client to make a query like:

```
mutation WritePost($body: String!){
  writePost(body: $body) {
    id
    posts {
      id
      body
    }
  }
}
```

Here Apollo will not only create or update the cache for all the returned posts, but it will also update the returned User object, including the list of posts.

**So why is this not commonly done? Why does Apollo's documentation suggest using `writeQuery` when adding or deleting nodes?**

The above will work fine when your schema is simple and you're working with a relatively small amount of data. However, returning the entire parent node, including all its relations, can be noticeably slower and more resource-intensive once you're dealing with more data. Additionally, in many apps a single mutation could impact multiple queries inside the cache. The same node could be returned by any number of fields in the schema, and even the same field could be part of a number of different queries that utilize different filters, sort parameters, etc.

These factors make it unlikely that you'll want to implement this pattern in production but there certainly are use cases where it may be a valid option.

Comment: Thanks for the "why" part - very useful!